# Using Grid with join on fields

Tags: atk4

I have two tables

table1: id, name, description
table2: id, name, description, idtable1 (FK of table1)

How can I make a Grid without using models but changing the dsql ? I mean maybe a join ?

I have tested using $g->dq->join('table1','table1.id=table2.idtable1')->field('name') but no success;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$grid=$page->add('Grid');
$grid->addColumn(..);
$grid->addColumn('text','table2_name');
$grid->setSource('table1');
$grid->dq->join('table2','table2.idtable1=table1.id')
      ->field('table2.name table2_name');
```

Comment: Roman, very thanks for your post. I'm going to give it a try.!!

Comment: n/p. You should mark one answer as "correct" on your questions.

Comment: Roman, I have a table that has two id fields referencig the same field on other table. Example: table1 id,name table2: iduser1,iduser2 (both are fk to id on table1). If I have on table1 (ex.) id 1 -> user1 and id 2->user2, and on table2 I have a pair 1,2. If I do that join, I only have twice the value "user1" when the true is that I need user1,user2. I have tested addinf another join() but without success. Can I have some help or maybe some direction about what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks a lot